# Go to recent directory of file using nautilus

Tags: nautilus

Is there any way to show recently visited file and directory in nautilus that i can quickly go to the page( ubuntu 11.10). I don't know why ubuntu is removing it's good features? This features was in nautilus till ubuntu 9.10(maybe). Ubuntu also replace full features control center with very less features system setting. Why we are trying to be MAC?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was recently asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/344446/is-there-a-way-to-make-nautilus-display-the-recently-used-files-and-directorie).

In summary - no, its not available in the current version of Nautilus - but the basic underlying capability is available through the GTK+3 libraries, hence you could (in theory) add this by adding the appropriate library call into a rebuild of nautilus.

If you want this - add your request to the [outstanding nautilus](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=325824) feature request report.

Comment: we can still use recent documents from nautilus file chooser. So there should be a link for recent document like for trash : trash:// etc.

Comment: @shantanu - agreed - it should in theory be possible with a bit of coding effort - however - I dont like the way the Gnome-Devs are going - they are stripping more and more nautilus features - just look what they have done to v12.10 version of nautilus.